# Убрать хешбанг (#!) с URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, редирект

Есть сайт, нужно сделать редирект со всех его страниц на главную страницу другого сайта. Этого я легко добился с помощью редиректа в .htaccess

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://новый.сайт/ [L,R=permanent]
```

Но есть ссылки со старого сайта с хешбангами, например старый.сайт/#!/cat и он ведет на новый.сайт/#!/cat
Как можно избавиться от этих хвостов при редиректе?

Comment: Никак, часть адреса после # не отправляется на сервер

Comment: эх, жаль.......